# xapian on CentOS 6 with PHP 5.3+

Tags: php, centos, xapian, centos6

I've got a 64bit server with CentOS 6 and PHP 5.3 installed

`php-5.3.2-6.el6_0.1.x86_64`

I've installed xapian using RPMs from their website

```
rpm-eprints-org-xapian-6-1.noarch
xapian-bindings-php-1.2.7-1.x86_64
xapian-core-libs-1.2.7-1.x86_64
xapian-bindings-1.2.7-1.x86_64
xapian-core-1.2.7-1.x86_64
```

Now when I try to use the xapian library from PHP through Apache, I get this error:

> Call to undefined function `dl()` in `/usr/share/php/xapian.php` on line 22

After some Googleing I found that `dl()` is no longer working in PHP 5.3+. I've enabled `enable_dl` in `php.ini`, didn't do anything. I've not been able to find any solution to this problem anywhere.  I guess there aren't many people using CentOS 6 at the moment?

What can I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the [xapian-bindings](http://xapian.org/docs/bindings/php/) are a PHP-extension you could just load it by adding the following to your php.ini:

```
extension = xapian.so
```

Btw. the [`dl`-manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.dl.php) says that `dl` is just disabled for certain "SAPIs" (and apparently mod_php is one of them).

One alternative would be to try php-cgi.

Comment: thank you for your answer, i've added that line to the php.ini. however it generated this error PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib64/php/modules/xapian.so' - /usr/lib64/php/modules/xapian.so: undefined symbol: zend_error_noreturn in Unknown on line 0

Comment: It seems like your extension is built for php 5.1 or 5.2. [This SO-question might give you a clue on how to resolve this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2556113/swig-generated-code-fails-to-run-on-php-5-3-2-undefined-symbol-zend-error-noret) although you probably have to compile the extensions manually.